# How can i change the html generated of filter field of views?

Tags: 6, views, theming

Mi problem is that my field (Filter Date-Popup of views) have the following html:

```
<div class="date-clear form-item"><div class="description">
  <div class="container-inline-date form-item date-clear-block"><div class="form-item" id="edit-date-filter-value-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item" id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0-wrapper">
    <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="date_filter[value][date]" id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0" size="20" value="" class="form-text">      <div class="description"> Format: 2012-09-17</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

But, in only need the following portion of this html:

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0-wrapper">
    <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="date_filter[value][date]" id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0" size="20" value="" class="form-text">      <div class="description"> Format: 2012-09-17</div>
  </div>
```

I try to do with create a template of the filter. With the Theme Information and rewrite the output of this HTML but doesn't work.

I work with Drupal 6 and Views 2

How can i do this? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 6, if you don't want to work with tpl, you can use [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews).

Comment: But, this module affect only the fields of the content of  views. But not the exposed filters.

Comment: Ok, you could try to add a hook_form_alter in a module and then see if you cane remove some element. Can I ask you because you have to change the html output?